# Fastly/Varnish response headers based on data center and cache status

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, fastly

I am trying to create a Varnish response header which would help me debug the state of the caches. I would like to create a header which would display the datacenters the request went through and age of the object. Something like:

```
X-Fastly-Age: VIE:2311s FRA:0s
```

Which would mean the object was cached in `VIE` data center (shield) and in the `FRA` edge it had to be fetched from `VIE`.

The second request would return something like:

```
X-Fastly-Age: VIE:2311s FRA:133s
```

I tried to set this:

```
set beresp.http.X-Fastly-Age = beresp.http.X-Fastly-Age " " req.http.edge-geo-datacenter ":" obj.entered;
```

This would work, but the problem is that:

- `beresp.http` cannot be written in `vcl_hit`
- `obj.entered` is not available in `vcl_fetch`

So basically it seems I don't have a place where to generate this header.

How can this be achieved?

EDIT:

I managed to run this in `vcl_deliver`:

```
set resp.http.X-Fastly-Age = resp.http.X-Fastly-Age " " server.datacenter ":" obj.entered;
```

getting:

```
> x-fastly-age: (null) DCA:0.001 FRA:0.001
```

It suffers from two things:

1. Getting `(null)` in the first call - is there a way to not prepend the header if it is null?
2. The edge time (FRA) never changes and stays on `0.001`. So it seems it is cached even with the obj.entered and never changes?

Comment: Do you need this or would using Fastly-Debug be sufficient? https://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/fastly-varnish/#fastly-debug

Comment: It might be useful to look into how Fastly's request flow works (https://developer.fastly.com/learning/vcl/using/), as it would help explain why it wouldn't make sense to set beresp within vcl_hit. 

Also I recommend reading up on Fastly's clustering model (https://developer.fastly.com/learning/vcl/clustering/) as that would help understand why HTTP headers set within certain vcl subroutines can disappear or not persist data correctly. 

I've written about clustering and adding a 'breadcrumb' header (and lots more) here: https://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/fastly-varnish/#breadcrumb-trail)

Comment: I'd also recommend using https://fiddle.fastlydemo.net/ for creating a reduced test case to validate things more easily.

Comment: re: avoiding null you can use the `if()` ternary syntax:

`set resp.http.X-Fastly-Age = if(resp.http.X-Fastly-Age, resp.http.X-Fastly-Age, "") " " server.datacenter ":" obj.entered;`

Alternatively you could use it with a variable declaration, which is more verbose, if you prefer avoiding inlining a conditional:

`declare local var.xfa STRING;
set var.xfa = if(resp.http.X-Fastly-Age, resp.http.X-Fastly-Age, "");
set resp.http.X-Fastly-Age = var.xfa " " server.datacenter ":" obj.entered;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to approach this purely from a Varnish point of view, since I have no experience with Fastly.

Varnish uses an `Age` header, which it sets automatically, to determine the age of an object in cache.

For uncached objects, the value of the `Age` response header is always zero. Non-zero values represent the age of an object accordingly.

And for the `null` values you're getting: we can use an `if/else` statement to solve that problem.

Here's some VCL for you:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
    if(resp.http.X-Fastly-Age) {
        set resp.http.X-Fastly-Age = resp.http.X-Fastly-Age + " " + server.datacenter + ":" + resp.http.Age;
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Fastly-Age = server.datacenter + ":" + resp.http.Age;
    }
}
```

Comment: `For uncached objects, the value of the Age response header is always zero.` this is in fact not true. If there is a cache before Varnish, which already sets the `Age` header, it will only extend it, so it will never be zero. Which is a reason I wanted to use internal Fastly `obj.entered` header to get actual Age in Fastly varnish.

Comment: @Vojtěch You're right. I forgot about the fact that Fastly uses multiple caching tiers. In that case I can't help you because I'm not too familiar with Fastly. However, I you have more Varnish questions, don't hesitate to reach out to me.